# Proposed FAQ question: Why was I downvoted?

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

*Sample*:

Why was my post downvoted? I ...

- have a lot of experience/am an expert in this field
- posted a thoughtful answer

and/or

- know that I'm right

... and I came to this community to contribute.  Why are my contributions not valued?

Comment: Purpose: Great for linking to.

Comment: I am not sure why this sort of explanation / FAQ would be necessary on this site, when it has not been found to be necessary on any other site in the network for 3 years.

Comment: That's a fair question.  First, I wouldn't say *necessary* - we could continue downvoting and using comments when needed.  Second, there is just a small distinction in downvoting here.  While "psuedo-answers" are a problem on all sites, here the umbrella covers many more answers than most sites. Partly due to stricter requirements, partly due to the wide variety of topics -- and questions that are easy for people to "think" they know the answer to.  I simply thought this would be an optimized way to handle those cases.